# how to change scrapy request queue size ? How to achieve strict DFO order

Tags: python, scrapy, twisted, depth-first-search

According to FAQ, Scrapy explores depth first but I noticed it will process 10 to 30 requests from start_urls before running any deeper requests.

Can I change a parameter and force scrapy to explore depth before processing start_urls ?

Reference http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/faq.html#does-scrapy-crawl-in-breadth-first-or-depth-first-order

Comment: Have you tried with [inline requests](https://pypi.org/project/scrapy-inline-requests/)?

Answer (score 0):

As [Apalala suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28392830/how-to-change-scrapy-request-queue-size-how-to-achieve-strict-dfo-order#comment92787263_28392830), if you really want to enforce a specific request order using Scrapy, [inline requests](https://pypi.org/project/scrapy-inline-requests/) are the way to go.

By design, Scrapy is not meant to follow a strict order for requests, and for most use cases [`Request.meta`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request.meta), priorities (from the [`Request` constructor](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request)) or even the [`DEPTH_PRIORITY` setting](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html?highlight=priority#depth-priority) you mention are enough.